# Determine transactions from users who visited a specific page

Tags: google-analytics

I'm hoping to confirm my understanding how how segments work in Google Analytics. I've created a segment with only the following Condition:

```
Page - contains - r=hp
```

Will this segment include any users who visited a page that includes "r=hp" at any point in the their session? Or am I misunderstanding how this "Page" condition works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct.

---

Above the input boxes it says:

**Filter** Sessions ▼  Include ▼

If you click "Sessions" you can change to "Users" to see a report for all users who went to that page at some point.